# React native axios calling action inside .then callback not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, axios

I'm having an issue calling an axios inside the axios post request .then method.

Getting the following error message:

> SyntaxError ... Unexpected token, expected , (145:82) (null)

*Line 145 is the .then callback after calling axios.*

Here's my code:

```
_handleImagePicked = async pickerResult => {
    this.setState({uploading: true})
    let uploadResponse, uploadResult;

    try {
      this.setState({ uploading: true });

      if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
        uploadResponse = await uploadImageAsync(pickerResult.uri);
        uploadResult = await uploadResponse.json();
        this.setState({ image: uploadResult.location });
        axios.post( `https://f1cdfd5fa4e.ngrok.io/api/update_photo?email=${this.props.email}&image=${uploadResult.location}`)
          .then(response => { this.props.profileUpdate({ prop: 'photo', response.data }) })
          .catch(error => console.log(error))

      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log({ uploadResponse });
      console.log({ uploadResult });
      console.log({ e });
      alert('Upload failed, sorry :(');
    } finally {
      this.setState({ uploading: false });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing { prop: 'photo', response.data } as argument to the callback 
but response.data cannot be added as a key
Try sending

this.props.profileUpdate({prop: 'photo', data:response.data})

Comment: Awesome in my case it was value:... not data:.. but it works thanks! I'm curious tho because I've been using this syntax for the rest of my application without specifying the 'data:' and it works fine, why isn't it working in this case?

Comment: For ex : var a = 1 ; var b = {a} is evaluated as var b = { a : a}